# How can I use an array for multiple sort functions

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to use an int array to pass through multiple sort methods.

ex) arr = {1, 3, 2, 9, 4}
pass arr through insertion sort, merge sort, and quick sort and get a sorted result but want to have arr stay the same.

I want to find an alternative of just copying the contents of arr and making a second array to pass through. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: Wonder, what's the idea behind sorting the same array by different sorting algorithms? Are you expecting different results? P.S. answering your question - use `Arrays.copyOf()` and do whatever you want with a duplicate, while the original one stays the same.

Comment: *"I want to find an alternative of just copying the contents of arr"* Do you mean an alternative to you copying the elements yourself? If so, then `arr2 = arr.clone()` would do it.

Comment: School project for analyzing sorting techiques @PavelSmirnov

Comment: Yes and no. I want to be able to use the same array (arr) and not have to make a clone or copy of it. @Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `arr` to remain unchanged, you have to create a copy of the array. You don't have a choice there.

Where you do have a choice is how you copy the array:

- `clone()`. ***Recommended***, but some people hate that method, even when it's the best option.

  ```java
  int[] arr2 = arr.clone();
  ```

  All arrays implement the `clone()` method, so says the bible, i.e. the *Java Language Specification*, section [10.7. Array Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-10.html):

  > The `public` method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the `clone` method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`.
  >
  > A clone of a multidimensional array is shallow, which is to say that it creates only a single new array. Subarrays are shared.
- [`Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#i19) *(Java 6+)*. Good alternative to `clone()`, but more wordy and requires an `import`.

  ```java
  int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
  ```
- [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-).

  ```java
  int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length];
  System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr2, 0, arr.length);
  ```
- Copy the contents manually, i.e. what you're asking for alternative to.

  ```java
  int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      arr2[i] = arr[i];
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could to create a function which return the same array that you want.

#### Example

```java
int[] getMyArray(){
    return new int[]{1, 3, 2, 9, 4};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it's very easy to keep the array during sort, just a bit more work. The arrays size is final but the values inside it aren't so you can just swap them.

Simple example:

```
 int[] arr = new int[] {1, 3, 2, 9, 4};
 int first = arr[0];
 int second = arr[1];
 arr[0] = second;
 arr[1] = first;
```

Now depending on the sort algorithm you probably need a second array, but in the end you can always copy the values back into your first array as long as the size doesn't change.